# if one div is showing hide the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out a way to hide one div using jQuery automatically when another div is on show. is there a way of doing this?

I am really new to jQuery and am still learning but I imagine it would be something like this:

```
 <script>
    (function () {
        if ($('.infobox-favourites').is(":visible")) {
             $(".infobox-more").fadeOut(500);


        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Does it work?

Comment: No clean solution if your elements change. You should change the code leading to your element becoming visible.

Comment: Right now your code should work. but it will be executed only once, after page is loaded. In that case if `.infobox-favourites` is visible(initially), jquery will hide `.infobox-more`. But your code will never be executed again. If you want to hide `.infobox-more` after div is hidden when some button is clicked, you should apply fadeOut to `infobox-more` in that button click handler as there is no event to notify you that div visibility is changed.

Comment: It depends where this code is in the context of your page as well. As I believe (function(){ should be $(function(){  <- notice the missing dollar on your version, which is the shorthand for jquery.ready()  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Check my answer, the demo I provided is working, now need some smart people to improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this JsBin Example http://jsbin.com/oreyeg/1/edit

Used this code

```
setInterval(function() {
  var div1 = $('.infobox-favourites').css("display");
        if (div1 != 'none') {
             $(".infobox-more").fadeOut(500);       
        }

    },200);
```

Used setInterval to execute the code after every 200ms to check for changes. You can remove it if you want it to execute only once.

Not sure what the problem was in. I guess the problem was with :visible, using :hidden must work too but in the example I used CSS method to get the value of display property and it worked.

**Note:** I tried to running the code without setInterval and it didn't worked :( but setTimeout helps in executing the script

```
setTimeout(function() {
//$(".div2").hide();  
  var div1 = $('.div1').css("display");
        if (div1 != 'none') {
          $(".div2").fadeOut(500);       
        }
  else {
  $(".div1").fadeIn(500);   
  }

    },0);
```